# google maps api - unwanted transparent borders

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Followed by this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple

and made a custom one

my html(almost same, main diff. are **var feartureOpts** and **var mapOtions**):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>
   var map;
   var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(52.330394, -23.661259);

   var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

   function initialize() {

     var featureOpts = [
       {
         stylers: [
           { gamma: 1.56 },
           { lightness: 25 },
           { saturation: -100 }
         ]
       }
     ];

     var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 17,
       disableDefaultUI: true,
       center: brooklyn,
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
       },
       mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
     };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
         mapOptions);

     var styledMapOptions = {
       name: 'Custom Style'
     };

     var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

     map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<div id="map-canvas" style="witdh: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
```

results: [image]

**QUESTION: how to remove those nasty semi-transparent square borders?**

Comment: fix the css rule that is applying to the map tiles (images).

Comment: just a typo from copying from source, ty

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/x5xXc/

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="witdh: 400px; height: 350px;"></div>
   var featureOpts = [
       {
         stylers: [
           { gamma: 1.56 },
           { lightness: 25 },
           { saturation: -100 }
         ]
       }
     ];
```

Comment: :) it's not that, I found out that my code was working when I did'nt applied it to my wordpress>page>post